# the questions about View.gone and View.Invisible in getView() of adapter

Tags: android, listview

I know the difference between `View.Gone` and `View.Invisible`,and I met a weird situation. I create a activity which contains views :

- `listView`
- `maskView`(custom ,nothing special but create a bitmap) (above listView)

I wanna make maskView visible when i click listView, but i find maskView don't show util i click second time on listView (the weird thing is I print Log and I find the `maskView.getVisibility() == Visible`,but I just can't see it on screen!But when i continue to click ,maskView show! Actually ,it just don't show at first time)or set maskView `View.Invisible` rather than `View.Gone`.

So let me show u how and when I set maskView's visibility and the respond of them.

1. at Activity

   1) a independent button, `button.click{ maskView.setVisible() }`

   2) or just `maskView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` directly after `findView`

   3) or at listView:

   ```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int position, long id) {
      maskView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
     }
    });
   ```

   they are all work!(er..i'm not kidding ,let's go on)
2. At adapter

   I make a observer in my adapter:

   ```
   private MaskViewListener maskViewListener;
   public interface MaskViewListener {
   void showMask(int mPiercedX, int mPiercedY, int mWidth, int mHeight);
   void cancelMask();
    }
   ```

   and my activity registers this listener.

   1)listView(at activity)

   ```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int position, long id) {
       mAdapter.getMaskViewListener().showMask(0,0,100,200);
       }
     });

     @Override
      public void showMask(int mPiercedX, int mPiercedY, int mWidth, int 
      mHeight) {
      if (maskView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
       maskView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       }
       }
   ```

   and it still work!!!!

   2) `getView()`

   ```
     private void maskByBigView(int position, View view, int section) {
     if (selectedPosition != DEFAULT_SELECTED_POSITION) {  
     if (selectedPosition == position) {
         maskViewListener.showMask(0,(int)view.getY(),200,200);            
        }
     }

     @Override
     public void showMask(int mPiercedX, int mPiercedY, int mWidth, int
   ```

   mHeight) {
         if (maskView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
           maskView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
          }

   and it happens the wired thing I told u above!!!
   and if i set maskView invisible rather than gone, and it works!!
3. so why only it don't work in `getView()` of an adapter , and it works after I set the maskView invisible rather than gone.
   and why if the other situation can ignore the maskView is invisible or gone.

Comment: [the maskView project](https://github.com/usedlie/maskViewOnListView)  ;   hey guys , here is the project. maybe it can explain more clearly!!  @pankaj yadav @ MrTy

Answer (score 0):

hey as i am able to understand your making view visible but your adapter dont have knowledge about it so call `adapter.notifiyDataStateChanged();` after making the view Visible

Comment: aha, I did call it ,other wise i will never see maskView

Comment: wait a moment , i post the project to gitHub ~

Comment: hello bro, i have post my project ; [the maskView](https://github.com/usedlie/maskViewOnListView)

Answer (score 0):

I think maskView you have not set the height and width for it.

In Listview, when maskView have gone, maskView height/width can be set 0, while invisible, it is always set to height and width.

Now, I think you should set width and height of maskView and Gone it.

Comment: i have try follow steps: 1) have set  width and height of maskView at xml ; 2) and then set maskView visible 3)and set maskView Gone immediately ；But it still don't work ; I will post project to gitHub latter.

Comment: OK, Mabey problem comes from your XML.
Try to use LinearLayout (Vertical) or FrameLayout